# How to fix the Zookeeper error for Hbase

Tags: virtual-machine, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Main OS is windows 7 64bit. Using VM player to create two vm CentOS 5.6 system. The net connection is bridge. I installed Hbase on both of the CentOS system， one is master, the other is slave. When I enter the shell, and run *status 'details'*.

The error from master is

> zookeeper.ZKConfig: no valid quorum servers found in zoo.cfg ERROR:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: An error is
>   preventing HBase from connecting to ZooKeeper

And the error from slave is

> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: HBase is
>   able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately.
>   This could be a sign that the server has too many connections (30 is
>   the default). Consider inspecting your ZK server logs for that error
>   and then make sure you are reusing HBaseConfiguration as often as you
>   can. See HTable's javadoc for more information.

Please give me some suggestion. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: The error is that the the zookeeper configuration is wrong - what's your zoo.cfg (in the zookeeper/conf/ dir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this is within your .bashrc, if not, add them and restart all hbase services (do not forget to manually run them as well), that did it for me with a pseudo-distributed installation. My problem (and maybe yours as well) was that Hbase wasn't detecting it's configuration.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export HBASE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hbase/conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this very often on my machine. I don't have a failsafe cure, but end up running stop-all.sh, and deleting every place that hadoop and dfs (its a dfs failure) store their temp files. It seems to happen after my computer goes to sleep while dfs is running.

I am going to experiment with single-user mode to avoid this. I dont need distribution while developing.